# Best way to import Entity Data Model to Project

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I am working with an MVVM layout but I want import my .edmx file as my "Model" only as a project instead of "Model" folder within my main project.

::Edit::
Main Question: When I import the "DataProject" (as I'm calling it) containing the EDMX & Designer file,  there are a zillion references to the main project's namespace. This makes me feel like if I were to just import the EDMX and Designer files rather than the whole containing DataProject into my MVVM project under the "Model" folder, that I would have to change all of these namespaces to the Main MVVM project namespace.

What do people normally do when importing an existing EDMX/designer file into their project to get the EDMX/designer to communicate properly with the main project they've imported to?

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question. Could you explain a bit more? What do you mean by "namespaces inconsistency"? (because otherwise, you can just put your .edmx file in a separate project, reference it from your main project and you're all set)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it's often easier just to recreate the model, but a using the Find and Replace dialog works just as well to find and replace the Entity Container Name and Namespace for the model.